# Laravel Sail SQL Connection timed out

Tags: laravel, laravel-sail

I just started using Laravel Sail, but Laravel can't connect to the MySQL server. Even Artisan in the container gives `Connection timed out`. I can connect from MySQL Workbench on my host machine.

My .env file has been updated for use with sail:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Comment: can you share  mysql part in docker-compose.yml file ?

Comment: @MohamedAhmed certainly!
```
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql:8.0'
        ports:
            - '3306:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
        volumes:
            - 'sailmysql:/var/lib/mysql'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel sail does not come with phpMyAdmin to visualize your database. so, you need to go with one of these:

- add phpMyAdmin to your docker-compose.yml file manually.

  ```
    services:
      ...
      phpmyadmin:
       image: phpmyadmin
       restart: always
       container_name: phpmyadmin
       depends_on:
        - mysql
       ports:
        - 8080:80
       environment:
        PMA_HOST: mysql
        MYSQL_USERNAME: "${DB_USERNAME}"
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${DB_PASSWORD}"
       networks:
        - sail
       healthcheck:
        test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"]
        retries: 3
        timeout: 5s
       ...
     volumes:
       ...
       phpmyadmin:
         driver: local
  ```

  restart your project again.

  ```
    sail up -d
  ```

  sail now will download phpMyAdmin image to your docker container where you
  will able to view database on port:8080 [http://localhost:8080/].
- use a graphical database management application like TablePlus as mentioned in [sail documentation.](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sail#interacting-with-sail-databases)

Comment: What has PHPMyAdmin to do with not being able to connect to the database?

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran across this issue too, when upgrading an old Laravel project from using `homestead` to `sail`. As per [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sail#mysql) you need to set `DB_HOST=mysql` in your `.env` file so that your application container can communicate with the MySQL container.

Answer (score -1):

You must write in "DB_HOST" are domain or ip

```
DB_HOST=1.2.3.4
```

or

```
DB_HOST=example.com
```

Comment: Hi! Laravel Sail is a docker system and mysql is the hostname for the server that it makes. There are multiple forum posts of people missing this line and thus beng unable to connect ( [for example](https://www.reddit.com/r/laravel/comments/klcwgy/laravel_sail_cant_connect_to_mysql/) ).

Comment: I think your host can't connect to this host. I work daily with Laravel and nobody in my company use the hostname as host. -- ping mysql --  can you ping this host?

Comment: Keep in mind that this is in the docker-compose environment by Sail, `mysql` is actually the hostname. If ping were installed on the container, I could ping it.